# First Click in button does not get the text in the EditText object

Tags: java, android

The problem is that when i click in the button the first time no text is in the EditText object, in the second click it works but does not replace the frame.

I Have one activity with a container for a fragment that has a editText and a button, when click the button i replace the fragment in the container with another fragment to display the text in the edit text.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLbsiE42JvE&list=PLshdtb5UWjSrOJfpFOE-u55s3SnY2EO9v&index=14

i'm in video "Android tutorial (2018) - 14 - Fragment to Fragment Communication".

The diference from this tutorial from my app is that my activity is the third in the same project, and i'm working in that activity as it was my main.

public class FinalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HeadLineFragment.OnMessageListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

    if(findViewById(R.id.final_activity_fragment)!= null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            HeadLineFragment headLineFragment = new HeadLineFragment();
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.final_activity_fragment, headLineFragment, null).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageSend(String message) {
    ArticleFragment articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("message",message);
    articleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.final_activity_fragment, articleFragment,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

}
```

}

---

public class HeadLineFragment extends Fragment {

```
OnMessageListener onMessageListener;
private Button button;
private EditText editText;
public interface OnMessageListener{
    public void onMessageSend(String message);
}

public HeadLineFragment(){

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.headline_fragment, container, false);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.bfrag);
    editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText21);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
           String s =  editText.getText().toString();
            onMessageListener.onMessageSend(message);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    try {
        onMessageListener = (OnMessageListener) activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnMessageListener....");

    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editText.setText("");
}
```

}

---

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

```
private TextView textView;

public ArticleFragment(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.article_fragment,container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message_display);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String message = bundle.getString("message");

    textView.setText(message);
    return view;
}
```

}

I expect that the functionality has the same behavior as in the video of the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved my own problem, the layout of the Activity had a fragment instead of a frame layout. By changing that the problem was solved.